# filter rows in a dataframe that contain a certain specific string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this example:
I want to filter only the rows that contain or start-with the word "Python" (small or uppercase)
(note..The number of columns and rows can vary in my regular data-frames)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "A": ['Python is Cool', 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11],
                        "B": ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z','w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                        "C": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','..PYTHON','test'],
                        "D": ['q', 'r', 's', 't','q', 'r', 's', 't'],
                        "X": ["B", "A", "D", "B", 'Pi','ABC','CD','2234'],
                        "Y": ["B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B","B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B"],
                        "Z": ["B,C", "A,B", "test Python", "A,B","B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B"]                
                        })
```

the output should return/ filter in this  data frames rows (0, 2 and 6) :

```
0  **Python is Cool**  w         a  q     B  B,C          B,C
2               6  y         c  s     D  C,D  **test Python**
6              10  y  **..PYTHON**  s    CD  C,D          C,D
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's customary to make an attempt at solving it and ask a concrete question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Python version 3.7

This will filter the rows by an arbitrary string. There may be a more efficient way to do it with the DataFrame methods but this will at least work.

It iterates over all the rows and then for each row iterates over the columns looking for the specific string. If it finds the string in a row it will skip to the next row. Worst case it will iterate over all items in the frame.

```
def filterDfByRow(df, string):
    toReturn = []

    for i in range(len(df)):
        for col in df.columns:
            item = df[col][i]
            if string.lower() in str(item).lower():
                toReturn.append(i)
                break

    return df.filter(items=toReturn, axis=0)
    

df = pd.DataFrame({ "A": ['Python is Cool', 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11],
                        "B": ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z','w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                        "C": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','..PYTHON','test'],
                        "D": ['q', 'r', 's', 't','q', 'r', 's', 't'],
                        "X": ["B", "A", "D", "B", 'Pi','ABC','CD','2234'],
                        "Y": ["B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B","B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B"],
                        "Z": ["B,C", "A,B", "test Python", "A,B","B,C", "A,B", "C,D", "A,B"]
                        })


filteredDf = filterDfByRow(df, 'python')

print(filteredDf)
```

Below is the output of this script

```
                A  B         C  D   X    Y            Z
0  Python is Cool  w         a  q   B  B,C          B,C
2               6  y         c  s   D  C,D  test Python
6              10  y  ..PYTHON  s  CD  C,D          C,D
```